# Java EE 6 Enterprise Application: Warning "Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point" when injecting a bean

Tags: servlets, netbeans, cdi, ear

I have created a fresh new Java EE 6 Enterprise-Application in Netbeans 7.2. So I have three Projects:

- EAR
- EJB
- WAR

In the EJB-Project, I have created a simple Bean:

```
package de.aidaorga.test;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;   
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class NewSessionBean2343 {
}
```

In the WAR-Project, I have created a blank beans.xml in the folder "Web Pages\WEB-INF":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

And I have also created a simple Servlet:

```
import de.aidaorga.test.NewSessionBean2343;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet2343", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet2343"})
public class NewServlet2343 extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    NewSessionBean2343 newSessionBean2343_1;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Now, Netbeans shows me a Warning "Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point" for the field "newSessionBean2343_1" annotated with "@Inject".

At deploy time, I get the following Excpetion:

```
Schwerwiegend: Exception while loading the app
Schwerwiegend: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [NewSessionBean2343] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject NewServlet2343.newSessionBean2343_1]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [NewSessionBean2343] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject NewServlet2343.newSessionBean2343_1]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:380)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why do I get this warning and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks for any help.

Markus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem: I've just forgotten the beans.xml in the EJB-Project. One beans.xml in an EAR-Project ist not enough...

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is just an IDE warning - what counts is whether your code compiles.

The code does not look wrong, even though I can't remember that I've ever injected one bean twice. But IMHO that should work.

I reckon that Netbeans is only able to validate `@Inject`, but not `@EJB`, this would explain the warning.

Try to deploy it to a server and see what comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed my question. The @EJB is removed now, and the exception at deploy time is attached.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to replace the contents `bean.xml` from:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       ...
>

</beans>
```

to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
       ...       
>

</beans>
```