# NullPointerException from EJB injected to servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, glassfish, ejb, cdi

Where does the `NullPointerException` reported in the Glassfish log originate?  The `ConverterServlet` seems to have `dollar` as a `BigInteger` number, non-null.  If `ConverterBean` would simply log the dollar amount that would be at least a step in the right direction.  Is the EJB not being injected correctly, perhaps?

The hard-coded dollar amount is output correctly:

> what is the amount? Servlet ConverterServlet at
>   /ConverterApplication-war amount is 999
>
> dollars: 999 class java.math.BigDecimal

but yen and euro are never executed because of the NPE reported in Glassfish:

```
[2017-04-17T00:12:27.609-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=84 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1492413147609] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[ConverterServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ConverterServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterServlet.processRequest(ConverterServlet.java:41)
    at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterServlet.doGet(ConverterServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

servlet:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.ejb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/")
public class ConverterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    ConverterBean converter;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ConverterServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("what is the amount?");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ConverterServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            String stringAmount = "999";
            out.println("amount is " + stringAmount);
            out.println("<p>");
            BigDecimal dollars = new BigDecimal(stringAmount);
            out.println("dollars:\t" + dollars + "\t" + dollars.getClass());
            out.println("<p>");

            BigDecimal yen = converter.dollarToYen(dollars);
            BigDecimal euros = converter.yenToEuro(yen);

            out.println("never executed..");
            out.println("yen");
            out.println(yen);
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("euros");
            out.println(euros);
            out.println("<p>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

and EJB:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.ejb;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class ConverterBean {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConverterBean.class.getName());
    private static final Level LEVEL = Level.INFO;
    private static final BigDecimal YEN_RATE = new BigDecimal("83.0602");
    private static final BigDecimal EURO_RATE = new BigDecimal("0.0093016");

    public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars) {
        return YEN_RATE;
    }
    public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen) {
        return EURO_RATE;
    }

    public BigDecimal realdollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars) {
        log.info("dollarToYen.." + dollars);
        BigDecimal result = dollars.multiply(YEN_RATE);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }

    public BigDecimal realyenToEuro(BigDecimal yen) {
        log.info("yenToEuro.." + yen);
        BigDecimal result = yen.multiply(EURO_RATE);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }

    private void lookup() throws NamingException {
        System.out.println("problem");
        PropertiesReader pr = new PropertiesReader();
        Properties webService = pr.getProps("WebService");
        log.info(pr.toString());
        log.info(new InitialContext().getEnvironment().toString());
    }

}
```

tree view of the application:

```
ConverterApplication/
├── build.xml
├── ConverterApplication-ejb
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── conf
│       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│       └── java
│           ├── net
│           │   └── bounceme
│           │       └── dur
│           │           └── ejb
│           │               ├── Client.java
│           │               ├── ConverterBean.java
│           │               └── PropertiesReader.java
│           └── resources
│               ├── JNDI.properties
│               └── WebService.properties
├── ConverterApplication-war
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── net
│   │           └── bounceme
│   │               └── dur
│   │                   └── ejb
│   │                       ├── ConverterServlet.java
│   │                       └── PropertiesReader.java
│   ├── test
│   └── web
│       ├── index.html
│       └── WEB-INF
│           └── web.xml
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    └── conf
        └── MANIFEST.MF

28 directories, 35 files
```

from:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-gettingstarted001.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add empty beans.xml files in classpaths of your ConverterApplication-war and ConverterApplication-ejb modules (in WEB-INF and META-INF folders). They need for discovering injected components.

Comment: this works.  But...it leads to this Netbeans "error":  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12168353/262852  and, I thought that beans.xml was outdated...  this requires further research.  I have no problem accepting this as the answer, but elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: @Thufir please show your updated tree view of the application.

Comment: updated app here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/43488182/262852  but it's just a WAR with local interface for EJB and not an EAR.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.ejb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/")
public class ConverterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    ConverterBean converter;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        converter = new ConverterBean();
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ConverterServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("what is the amount?");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ConverterServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            String stringAmount = "999";
            out.println("amount is " + stringAmount);
            out.println("<p>");
            BigDecimal dollars = new BigDecimal(stringAmount);
            out.println("dollars:\t" + dollars + "\t" + dollars.getClass());
            out.println("<p>");

            BigDecimal yen = converter.dollarToYen(dollars);
            BigDecimal euros = converter.yenToEuro(yen);

            out.println("never executed..");
            out.println("yen");
            out.println(yen);
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("euros");
            out.println(euros);
            out.println("<p>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

however, instantiating the bean shouldn't be required.  Correct or false?

see:

[NullPointerException in ejb injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656710/nullpointerexception-in-ejb-injection)

Comment: This is not the correct answer. You're getting an NPE because you appear to be deploying separate EJB jar and WAR modules.  The WAR file classes will not be able to see the EJB classes. In the old days you would package both in an EAR file. But with Java EE 6 and newer you can just put all the classes in your WAR file - or include the EJB jar file in your WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: I don't entirely follow.  Yes, my inclination was to seperate out the EJB from WAR.  I only jammed them together so that it would be easier to deploy as an EAR.  If you would elaborate that would be appreciated.

Comment: Java EE dictates rules for class visibility between modules and deployments. In general separate deployments cannot see each other's classes.