# Glassfish error: NameNotFoundException so servlet cannot inject EJB

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, web-inf

Where and how should the EJB `ConverterBean` be located so that `ConverterServlet` can inject the EJB?  Does not:

["..with Java EE 6 and newer you can just put all the classes in your WAR file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447158/nullpointerexception-from-ejb-injected-to-servlet/43482404#comment73950331_43447167)

I'm reading the Java EE 7 tutorial on this topic, of course.

the `InjectionException` from the browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter,Remote 3.x interface =net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,refType=Session into class net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter,Remote 3.x interface =net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,refType=Session into class net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter,Remote 3.x interface =net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean not found]]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet/converter,Remote 3.x interface =net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean not found]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean not found]

root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean not found

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
```

Excerpt from `tail -f` of the Glassfish log from deployment to `NameNotFoundException`:

```
[2017-04-18T23:23:53.687-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033687] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.709-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033709] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.719-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033719] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.725-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033725] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.757-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033757] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB ConverterBean: [java:global/ConverterWebAppicationArchiveWithEJB/ConverterBean, java:global/ConverterWebAppicationArchiveWithEJB/ConverterBean!net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBeanLocal]]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.787-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033787] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.795-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033795] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.799-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033799] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.966-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033966] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [ConverterWebAppicationArchiveWithEJB] at [/ConverterWebAppicationArchiveWithEJB]]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:53.976-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=154 _ThreadName=admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1492583033976] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ConverterWebAppicationArchiveWithEJB was successfully deployed in 294 milliseconds.]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:54.263-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1492583034263] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet as unavailable]]

[2017-04-18T23:23:54.272-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1492583034272] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet]: Allocate exception for servlet net.bounceme.dur.servlets.ConverterServlet
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:636)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:485)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

servlet trying to inject `ConverterBean`:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import net.bounceme.dur.ejb.ConverterBean;

@WebServlet("/converter")
public class ConverterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    ConverterBean converter;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        // converter = new ConverterBean();
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ConverterServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("what is the amount?");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ConverterServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            String stringAmount = "999";
            out.println("amount is " + stringAmount);
            out.println("<p>");
            BigDecimal dollars = new BigDecimal(stringAmount);
            out.println("dollars:\t" + dollars + "\t" + dollars.getClass());
            out.println("<p>");

            //   BigDecimal yen = converter.dollarToYen(dollars);
            //   BigDecimal euros = converter.yenToEuro(yen);
            out.println("never executed..");
            out.println("yen");
            //    out.println(yen);
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("euros");
            //    out.println(euros);
            out.println("<p>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

the `tree` structure of the project:

```
.
├── build.xml
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
├── src
│   ├── conf
│   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── java
│       └── net
│           └── bounceme
│               └── dur
│                   ├── ejb
│                   │   ├── ConverterBean.java
│                   │   ├── ConverterBeanLocal.java
│                   │   └── PropertiesReader.java
│                   └── servlets
│                       └── ConverterServlet.java
├── test
└── web
    ├── index.html
    └── WEB-INF
        └── web.xml

13 directories, 14 files
```

I tried putting the `servlet` and `ConverterBean` in the same package, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have defined a local interface for `ConverterBean` called `ConverterBeanLocal`.

Therefore you will need to use that at the injection point:

```
@WebServlet("/converter")
public class ConverterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    ConverterBeanLocal converter;
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `ConverterBeanLocal` interface altogether and make your code simpler.